# Data visualisation usually shows progress, but I want to show what needs to be done instead

Tags: info-visualisation, dashboard

I'm having an issue regarding dashboard design. I'm designing an operational dashboard and for my users, they need to see what needs to be done instead of knowing how much they've done. For example, they have 12 applications they need to submit and they submitted 9. Currently, I tried designing with the usual data charts like a bar chart or a radial bar, I.e. a 75% filled bar. [image]

The image above is just an example. So the issue comes when I want to alert them about the 3 applications they've yet to submit. It does not seem to flow because the chart shows completion, but the numbers (the more important information) shows incompletion.

Please let me know of any suggestions you have or any resources that you think can help me, greatly appreciated :')

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see, according to what is written in the question, is that having to show that both figures are related but belong to different elements:

- Percentage of work done
- Items to add

... the image shows both at the same level of perception.

---

Regardless of the chart type, I would try three things:

- Isolate each information group (*see the [Gestalt law of closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping)*)
- Contrast the two types of information to establish a difference (*see [graphic contrast](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/130355/115107)*)
- Graphically show or imply the relationship that exists between them

[image]

Comment: Thank you Danielillo for your explanation, I will try that and see how it goes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a circle that displays the percent completed, the number of steps, which steps are completed and which aren't.

This could be an interface too. The sections could be buttons.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Is the information of how many have been completed relevant? To me it sounds as if that does not need to be displayed at all, at least not prominently.
Maybe it is only necessary to show:

> applications that need to be submitted: 3

Of course, the feeling of accomplishment is lost this way.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Likewise, I was wondering if it needs to be displayed. So I am going to do some user testing because it does seem weird if I display a progress bar for things not completed :o But my users use them on a daily basis, so maybe it's something they can 'learn'? Not sure, but will see how UT goes ;)